# Convergence between two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a_{n}$ converges to $a$ and $b_{n}$ converges to $b$, then the sequence $<a_{n} + b_{n}>$ converges to $a + b$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$, since $a_{n}$ converges to $a$, then there exists a positive integer $n_{0}$ such that $$n > n_{0} \Rightarrow |a_{n} - a| < \epsilon$$ Also, since $b_{n}$ converges to $b$ then there also exists a positive integer $n_{0}$ such that $$n > n_{0} \Rightarrow |b_{n} - b| < \epsilon$$. So, now we can choose an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{n}| < \epsilon/2$ and $|b_{n}| < \epsilon/2 \forall n\geq N$. Hence, $\forall n\geq N$ we have $$|a_{n} + b_{n}| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$$. Therefore, $|a_{n} + b_{n}|$ converges to $a + b$.

Note: I am not sure if I am right with this proof but I don't see why it would be wrong, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the triangle inequality $|a_n+b_n-a-b| \leq |a_n-a|+|b_n-b|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $n_{0}$ is not necessarily the same for $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$.

So let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exist $n_{0}$, $n_{1}$, that for all $n>n_{0}$:
$|a_{n} - a| < \epsilon/2$

And for all $n>n_{1}$: $|b_{n} - b| < \epsilon/2$.
Finally:

$|(a_{n}+b_{n}) - (a+b)| = |(a_{n}-a) + (b_{n} - b)| \leq |a_{n}-a| + |b_{n} - b|< \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$

for all $n > m = max(n_{0}, n_{1})$